# Split method not working as expected

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I tried to use a Split Function to separate the input String by Space character into a String Array but nothing happened.

I used this code:

```
String a;
String[] b = new String[4];
a=input.next(); // input : 1 2 3 4
b=a.split(" "); // or b=a.split("\\s+");
/* output : b[0]=1 , b[1]=Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
*/
```

But when I defined a value like this:

```
String a="1 2 3 4";
```

Everything is done successfully.

What should I do?

Comment: `input.next()` is not returning what you think it is.  What type is `input`?

Comment: Assuming that `input` is a `Scanner` reference, you should use `input.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `input` is a `Scanner`...

The `next()` method will return the next token, and by default, [`Scanner` separates input by whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  You don't need to `split` the input when `Scanner` is tokenizing the input for you already.

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be
>   converted into values of different types using the various next
>   methods.

Alternatively, you could use `input.nextLine()` to get the entire line, then you can `split` the line yourself.